# Roboto font rendering poorly in new-look Gmail (Mac)

Tags: fonts, gmail, rendering, google-fonts, roboto

The new-look Gmail has just been released and it replaces Arial in its UI with Roboto throughout. Roboto renders fine in other apps (Drive, e.g.) but in the new Gmail (both Chrome and Safari) the font rendering is blurry, with varying thicknesses, inconsistent kerning and poor anti-aliasing.

For example:

[image: click here for example]

or:

[image: another here]

Look at the differences between the vertical strokes of the R and the E in the word REMOTE. The font is heavily anti-aliased but not consistently. The default font size has also dropped and this, combined with the blurriness, has impacted the readability.

I'm using all the defaults for Gmail, Chrome. I've double-checked I don't have the Roboto font installed on my machine. I have tried installed Roboto (via Google's SkyFonts), though this had no effect. Font now uninstalled.

Would anyone know how I can diagnose this and understand why the font is rendering poorly?

Comment: As a question around how to change the applied CSS for a random website on the web, this question feels like it should really be "how do I use a custom stylesheet" (which you should not ask: it already has lots of answers both on SO as well as on the internet at large).